# facing issue with the upload of the website on IIS7.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis-7, web-deployment

I am trying to upload my website to hosting space which looks to be using IIS 7.5. Website uploads but when I try to view it is generates error. the issue is not very obvious . but the error says that there is some problem with the web.config but on the development machine it is ok. check the www.spiralsnet.com for further detailed error message. I am not sure what is cuasing this issue. please help.

Comment: Is your dev machine .NET 3.5 or .NET 4.x? What about the host? Try removing the duplicate scriptResourceHandler as the error indicates.

Comment: No there is no duplicate I removed but then it went further to another handler and said this is duplicate and so on.. My dev machine is .net 3.5

Comment: @SpiralsWhirls: There isn't a duplicate in *your config alone*, but, when combined with configs in higher folders, there is.  Remove all duplicates.

Comment: This will happen if your dev machine is on .NET 3.5 but the host is on .NET 4.x, because those config sections are predefined in .NET 4.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hosting space has a web.config higher up that already defines the `scriptResourceHandler` section.  Remove the definition from your config.

In the Detailed Error Information section of your error page, the specific error is provided

> Config Error: There is a duplicate 'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler' section 
>   defined

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382489/development-enivroment-of-3-5-and-hosting-4-x-conflicts-issues

Answer (score 2):

As the error message states:

> There is a duplicate 'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler' section defined

Remove the entry from your web configuration and try again.

Comment: Both the answers are correct... which one should be accepted... confused

Comment: @SpiralsWhirls Any you see fit. They are largely the same, so whichever helped you _most_, or toss a coin.

Comment: Ok.. I think the zimdanen answer let me the clue into the main cause of the conflict.... anyway thanks for help..

Comment: I am asking another question in similar domain of version conflicts so please try to answer that one too...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382489/development-enivroment-of-3-5-and-hosting-4-x-conflicts-issues